# Clear input fields inside a bootstrap modal on button click without closing it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-modal

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('#HTT',#HMT,#HTI,#HMI).val('');">Clean</button>
```

Im triying to clear four inputs in a bootstrap modal it gets closed. What can I do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/onnjee48/

Comment: [this works though](http://jsfiddle.net/onnjee48/3/)

as per @Ashutosh Tiwari's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong put single qoute at start and end try this:

> $('#HTT, #HMT, #HTI, #HMI')

Comment: it will work    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('#HTT, #HMT, #HTI, #HMI').val('');">Clean</button>